# Wordpress custom taxonomy check box to dropdown

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, filters, jquery, hooks

Hi my custom taxonomy name is country.In this  A is a country, a-sub1,a-sub2 are states under A. b-sub1,b-sub2 are state under Country B.

Now  i need to display the country list(parent) box and state box in two separated listing.

When admin select A , then only  states box is displayed and under state box  the states of A is displayed  .Similar way when admin select B, then states under B is displayed on other box .

How to do this? .Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps to achieve your result,

1. Use [get_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to fetch all of your parent taxonomies and render a drop-down with the title and setting a data attribute with the term ID. Please set the args "parent" to 0 and taxonomy to your taxonomy slug.
2. Write a jQuery script to fire an AJAX on the above created drop-down. The AJAX should send the selected term ID and should handle the request by sending a JSON reply of an array of the child term titles and IDs using the function [get_term_children](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children)
3. Handle the JSON encoded array in the AJAX complete/success callback of jQuery to add the sub-taxonomies into the other drop-down.